# How to randomly sample a subset of a file

Tags: command-line, files, command

Is there any Linux command one can use to sample subset of a file? For instance, a file contains one million lines, and we want to randomly sample only one thousand lines from that file.

For random I mean that every line gets the same probability to be chosen and none of the lines chosen are repetitive.

`head` and `tail` can pick a subset of the file but not randomly. I know I can always write a python script to do so but just wondering is there a command for this usage.

Comment: lines in random order, or a random block of 1000 consecutive lines of that file?

Comment: Every line gets the same probability to be chosen. Don't need to be consecutive although there is a tiny probability that a consecutive block of lines be chosen together. I've updated my question to clearer about that. Thanks.

Comment: My https://github.com/barrycarter/bcapps/tree/master/bc-fastrand.pl does this approximately by seeking to a random location in the file and finding the nearest newlines.

Answer (score 124, accepted):

The `shuf` command (part of coreutils) can do this:

```
shuf -n 1000 file
```

And at least for now non-ancient versions (added in a [commit from 2013](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/commit/20d7bce0f7e57d9a98f0ee811e31c757e9fedfff)), that will use reservoir sampling when appropriate, meaning it shouldn't run out of memory and is using a fast algorithm.

Comment: According to documentation, it needs a sorted file as input: http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#toc_Operating-on-sorted-files

Comment: @Ketan, doesn't seem that way

Comment: @Ketan it's just in the wrong section of the manual, I believe. Note that even the examples in the manual are not sorted. Note also that `sort` is in the same section, and it clearly doesn't require sorted input.

Comment: Yes, true. I tried the command, works well.

Comment: `shuf` was introduced to coreutils in version `6.0 (2006-08-15)`, and believe it or not, some reasonably-common systems (CentOS 6.5 in particular) don't have that version :-|

Comment: If only a random subset, not in a random order, is required, then shuf is very inefficient: better is to do reservoir sampling, as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/692401/933228).

Comment: @petrelharp `shuf -n` does reservoir sampling, at least when the input is greater than 8K, which is the size they determined is benchmarks better. See the source code (e.g., at https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/shuf.c#L46 ). Sorry for this very late answer. Apparently that's new as of 6 years ago.

Answer (score 45):

If you have a **very large** file (which is a common reason to take a sample) you will find that:

1. `shuf` exhausts memory
2. Using `$RANDOM` won't work correctly if the file exceeds 32767 lines

**If you don't need "exactly" n sampled lines** you can **sample a ratio** like this:

`cat input.txt | awk 'BEGIN {srand()} !/^$/ { if (rand() <= .01) print $0}' > sample.txt`

**This** uses **constant memory**, samples 1% of the file (if you know the number of lines of the file you can adjust this factor to sample a close to a limited number of lines), and **works with any size** of file but it **will not** return a **precise** number of lines, just a statistical ratio.

*Note: The code comes from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/692312/randomly-pick-lines-from-a-file-without-slurping-it-with-unix*

Comment: If a user wants *approximately* 1% of the non-blank lines, this is a pretty good answer. But if the user wants an *exact* number of lines (e.g., 1000 out of a 1000000-line file), this fails. As the answer you got it from says, it yields only a statistical estimate. And do you understand the answer well enough to see that it is ignoring blank lines? This might be a good idea, in practice, but undocumented features are, in general, not a good idea.

Comment: P.S.  *Simplistic* approaches using `$RANDOM` won’t work correctly for files larger than 32767 lines.  The statement “Using `$RANDOM` doesn’t reach the entire file” is a bit broad.

Comment: @G-Man The question seems to talk about getting 10k lines from a million as an example. None of the answers around did work for me (because of the size of the files and hardware limitations) and I propose this as a reasonable compromise.
It won't get you 10k lines out of a million but it might be close enough for most practical purposes.
I've clarified it a bit more following your advise. Thanks.

Comment: This is the best answer, the lines are picked randomly while respecting the chronological order of the original file, in case this is a requirement. In addition `awk` is more resource friendly than `shuf`

Comment: If you need an exact number, you can always… Run this with a % greater than your need. Count the result. Remove lines matching count mod difference.

Comment: This is also useful if you're not operating on a "file" as such but a long-running stream, and you need to get output immediately. I'm writing a tool to migrate data between data centers which will run for a long time and I'd like to see a sample of the data but not all of it.

Answer (score 16):

Similar to @Txangel's probabilistic solution but approaching 100x faster.

```
perl -ne 'print if (rand() < .01)' huge_file.csv > sample.csv
```

If you need high performance, an exact sample size, and are happy to live with a sample gap at end of the file, you can do something like the following (samples 1000 lines from a 1m line file):

```
perl -ne 'print if (rand() < .0012)' huge_file.csv | head -1000 > sample.csv
```

.. or indeed chain a second sample method instead of `head`.

Comment: Successfully applied the first method to a 10GB file which was also gzipped, so I used `zcat huge_file.csv.gz | perl -ne ...`. Took 30 minutes or so. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7):

In case the `shuf -n` trick on large files runs out of memory and you still need a fixed size sample and an external utility can be installed then try [sample](http://www.fresse.org/sample/):

```
$ sample -N 1000 < FILE_WITH_MILLIONS_OF_LINES
```

The caveat is that the *sample* (1000 lines in the example) must fit into memory.

Disclaimer: I am the author of the recommended software.

Comment: For those who install it and have their `/usr/local/bin` before `/usr/bin/` in their path, be wary that macOS comes with a built-in call-stack sampler called `sample`, which does something completely different, in `/usr/bin/`.

Answer (score 3):

I like using awk for this when I want to preserve a header row, and when the sample can be an approximate percentage of the file. Works for very large files:

```
awk 'BEGIN {srand()} !/^$/ { if (rand() <= .01 || FNR==1) print > "data-sample.txt"}' data.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Not aware of any single command which could do what you ask but here is a loop I put together which can do the job:

```
for i in `seq 1000`; do sed -n `echo $RANDOM % 1000000 | bc`p alargefile.txt; done > sample.txt
```

`sed` will pick up a random line on each of the 1000 passes. Possibly there are more efficient solutions.

Comment: Is it possible to get the same line multiple times in this approach?

Comment: Yes, quite possible to get the same line number more than once. Additionally, `$RANDOM` has a range between 0 and 32767. So, you will not get a well spread line numbers.

Comment: does not work - random is called once

Answer (score 2):

You can save the follow code in a file (by example randextract.sh) and execute as:

```
randextract.sh file.txt
```

---- BEGIN FILE ----

```
#!/bin/sh -xv

#configuration MAX_LINES is the number of lines to extract
MAX_LINES=10

#number of lines in the file (is a limit)
NUM_LINES=`wc -l $1 | cut -d' ' -f1`

#generate a random number
#in bash the variable $RANDOM returns diferent values on each call
if [ "$RANDOM." != "$RANDOM." ]
then
    #bigger number (0 to 3276732767)
    RAND=$RANDOM$RANDOM
else
    RAND=`date +'%s'`
fi 

#The start line
START_LINE=`expr $RAND % '(' $NUM_LINES - $MAX_LINES ')'`

tail -n +$START_LINE $1 | head -n $MAX_LINES
```

---- END FILE ----

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do here with RAND, but `$RANDOM$RANDOM` does not generate random numbers in the whole range “0 to 3276732767” (for example, it will generate 1000100000 but not 1000099999).

Comment: The OP says, “Every line gets the same probability to be chosen.  … there is a tiny probability that a consecutive block of lines be chosen together.” I also find this answer to be cryptic, but it looks like it is extracting a 10-line block of consecutive lines from a random starting point. That is not what the OP is asking for.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the number of lines in the file (like 1e6 in your case), you can do:

```
awk -v n=1e6 -v p=1000 '
  BEGIN {srand()}
  rand() * n-- < p {p--; print}' < file
```

If not, you can always do

```
awk -v n="$(wc -l < file)" -v p=1000 '
  BEGIN {srand()}
  rand() * n-- < p {p--; print}' < file
```

That would do two passes in the file, but still avoid storing the whole file in memory.

Another advantage over GNU `shuf` is that it preserves the order of the lines in the file.

Note that it assumes `n` *is* the number of lines in the file. If you want to print `p` out of the *first* `n` lines of the file (which has potentially more lines), you'd need to stop `awk` at the `n`<sup>th</sup> line like:

```
awk -v n=1e6 -v p=1000 '
  BEGIN {srand()}
  rand() * n-- < p {p--; print}
  !n {exit}' < file
```

Answer (score 1):

Or like this:

```
LINES=$(wc -l < file)  
RANDLINE=$[ $RANDOM % $LINES ]  
tail -n $RANDLINE  < file|head -1
```

From the bash man page:

```
        RANDOM Each  time this parameter is referenced, a random integer
              between 0 and 32767 is generated.  The sequence of random
              numbers  may  be initialized by assigning a value to RAN‐
              DOM.  If RANDOM is unset, it loses  its  special  proper‐
              ties, even if it is subsequently reset.
```

Comment: This fails badly if the file has fewer than 32767 lines.

Comment: This will output ***one*** line from the file. (I guess your idea is to execute the above commands in a loop?) If the file has *more* than 32767 lines, then these commands will choose only from the first 32767 lines.  Aside from possible inefficiency, I don’t see any big problem with this answer if the file has fewer than 32767 lines.

Answer (score 1):

If you file size isn't huge, you can use Sort random. This takes a little longer than shuf, but it randomizes the entire data. So, you could easily just do the following to use head as you requested:

```
sort -R input | head -1000 > output
```

This would sort the file randomly and give you the first 1000 lines.

Answer (score 1):

To get a single random block of adjacent lines, use `shuf` to get one random line, then use `grep` to get the block of lines after the randomly selected line.

```
$ shuf -n 1 file | grep -f - -A 10 file
```

This will access the file twice. The -f parameter tells grep to get the search pattern from file, in this case stdin (by using a dash as the value to the f parameter) which is the single randomly selected line from the file.

A simple function:

```
function random-block {
  shuf -n 1 $1 | grep -f - -A $(($2>0?$2-1:0)) $1
}
```

Example usage:

```
$ random-block /var/log/syslog 10
```

Indeed, this will not guarantee an output of the requested number of lines if the random selection is so far down that there aren't enough lines left when selecting the block.

An enhanced function might look like this:

```
function random-block {
  head -n $(($(wc -l | cut -f1 -d ' ')-$2+1)) $1 | shuf -n 1 | grep -f - -A $(($2>0?$2-1:0)) $1
}
```

This would grab all the lines in the file except the last n lines and then shuffle that list of lines. This would ensure that grep can always select the requested number of lines.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the accepted answer, GNU `shuf` supports simple random sampling (`shuf -n`) quite well. If sampling methods beyond those supported by `shuf` are needed, consider [tsv-sample](https://ebay.github.io/tsv-utils/docs/tool_reference/tsv-sample.html) from [eBay's TSV Utilities](https://github.com/eBay/tsv-utils). It supports several additional sampling modes, including weighted random sampling, Bernoulli sampling, and distinct sampling. Performance is similar to GNU `shuf` (both are quite fast). Disclaimer: I am the author.

Answer (score 0):

About around the time this question was first asked, I had written a C99-based utility called `sample` (https://github.com/alexpreynolds/sample) that does reservoir sampling on text files.

My `sample` tool will only use 8 bytes per line, which means that very large files can be sampled from with much less memory.

In contrast, the `shuf` and other tools mentioned above can read the entire file into system memory, which can often lead to `out-of-memory` errors.

Here's the help statement to summarize features:

```
$ sample --help
sample
  version: 1.0
  author:  Alex Reynolds

Usage: sample [--sample-size=n] [--lines-per-offset=n] [--sample-without-replacement | --sample-with-replacement] [--shuffle | --preserve-order] [--hybrid | --mmap | --cstdio] [--rng-seed=n] <newline-delimited-file>

  Performs reservoir sampling (http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/3147.3165) on very large input
  files that are delimited by newline characters. The approach used in this application
  reduces memory usage by storing a pool of byte offsets to the start of each line, instead
  of the line elements themselves.

  If the sample size (--sample-size) parameter is omitted, then the sample binary will shuffle
  the entire file.

  For text files delimited by multiples of lines, specify a --lines-per-offset value.

  Process Flags:

  --sample-size=n               | -k n    Number of samples to retrieve (n = positive integer; optional)
  --lines-per-offset=n          | -l n    Number of lines per offset (n = positive integer; optional, default=1)
  --sample-without-replacement  | -o      Sample without replacement (default)
  --sample-with-replacement     | -r      Sample with replacement (optional)
  --shuffle                     | -s      Shuffle sample written to standard output (default)
  --preserve-order              | -p      Preserve order of sample written to standard output (optional)
  --mmap                        | -m      Use memory mapping for handling input file (default)
  --cstdio                      | -c      Use C I/O routines for handling input file (optional)
  --hybrid                      | -y      Use hybrid of C I/O routines and memory mapping for handling input file (optional)
  --rng-seed=n                  | -d n    Initialize the Twister RNG with a specific seed value (n = positive integer; optional)
  --help                        | -h      Show this usage message
```

To install it:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/alexpreynolds/sample.git
$ cd sample
$ make 
$ cp sample /usr/local/bin
```

To use it, in the most basic case:

```
$ sample -k 1234 some_file.txt > some_file.sample.txt
```

This draws 1234 random lines from `some_file.txt` and writes them to `some_file.sample.txt`.